# oracle ,sql code ,column not allowed here

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I was using the below Query to save exception to my table

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  INSERT INTO TEMP_ERR(COLUMN1)
  VALUES(SQLCODE);
```

The above query threw

> "SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here"

on an trial-error basis i tried,

```
EXCEPTION

  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DECLARE m VARCHAR(255);
   m:=SQLCODE;
  INSERT INTO TEMP_ERR(COLUMN1)
  VALUES(m);
```

it worked.why?somebody guide me the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3372
see a topic: "Retrieving the Error Code and Error Message: SQLCODE and SQLERRM"

> You cannot use SQLCODE or SQLERRM directly in a SQL statement.
>   Instead, you must assign their values to local variables, then use the
>   variables in the SQL statement, as shown in Example 10-11.